# Sending objects as JSON vs Objects of defined class

Tags: java, json

I have multiple web services running on Tomcat servers with Java backend. When one of the services queries for something from one of the other services, it returns the payload as a JSON string. Now i need to parse this and get the info that i need. I use the JSON library provided by json.org

What I wanted to ask is that, will be faster (wrt to processing) if i have a template class (i class with just attributes and their get/setters) as a library class in both the services and then pass the payload as an object of that class, and then accept it as by type casting to that object.

```
WebResource localWebResource = localClient.resource(url);
ClientResponse localClientResponse = (ClientResponse) localWebResource
    .accept(new String[] { "application/json" }).get(ClientResponse.class);

//Scenario 1 - accept it as String 
String jsonString = (String) localClientResponse.getEntity(String.class);
MyObject myObj = parseJson(jsonString);
```

//Scenario 2 - accept it as object of 'MyObject'

```
MyObject myObj = (MyObject) localClientResponse.getEntity(MyObject.class);
```

Using scenario 2, will it be any faster compared to scenario 1. Converting to 'MyObject' in scenario 2, will the compiler take the same amount of time as for manual parsing like in scenario 1?.

Note that the payload is transferred over the network. Will either of this approach have any effect on the network transfer time?

Comment: Are you not using Spring framework?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, both methods would take the same amount of time. They both have to transform the JSON string into an object graph. However, my experience is that getting the object from the framework is much faster than trying to do it myself. (using Jersey 1.17, no Jackson, Jaxb/Json conversion)

Comment: So even if I send it as an Object of type 'MyObject', over the network it will come as a JSONString itself?

Comment: yes, assuming you have annotated your method and object correctly. Specifically, the method must have @produces("application/json"), and the object is tagged with @XmlRootElement (and conforms to the JAXB requirements)